# Hide elements of a list by category with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this mock code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input[name=type_selector]").change(function(){
                    var $category = $(this);
                    $("div[class=widget_group_div]").each(function(){
                        if ($category.parent().text() == $(this).children("p").text())
                        {
                            if ($category.prop('checked')) 
                            {
                                $(this).children().show();
                                $(this).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $(this).children().hide();
                                $(this).hide();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul id="classification_selector">
                <label><li>widget_a<input type="checkbox" name="type_selector" value="widget_a" checked=""/></li></label>
                <label><li>widget_b<input type="checkbox" name="type_selector" value="widget_b" checked=""/></li></label>               
            </ul>
            <div id="y_scroll_div">
                <div class="name_div"><h3><label>Item 1231</label></h3></div>
                <div class="widget_group_div">              
                    <label class="widgets_name">
                        <p class="widget_group_name">
                            widget_a
                        </p>
                    </label>                    
                </div>
                <div class="name_div"><h3><label>Item 23232</label></h3></div>
                <div class="widget_group_div">                  
                    <label class="widgets_name">
                        <p class="widget_group_name">
                            widget_b
                        </p>
                    </label>                    
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is suppose to happen is that there is suppose to be a big list of items each with a name_div class. Then underneath there would be a bunch of different elements, in the widget_group_div, with info on that item, and one element that would classify that item under a category, for simplicity I removed all the other elements but the one dealing with category.

The top of the page features a check list with the available categories, the idea being that the page loads with everything in the system. Then the user can choose to eliminate categories by removing checks from the category list. Ideally the name_div right above each widget_group_div would be hidden as well, but as of right now I cannot even get the widget_group_div, or its children, to hide.

I have included my attempt at the jquery, to give you an idea of the direction I am trying to head in, thanks.

Comment: invalid markup label can't be children of ul.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly good attempt you are very close,
Secondly I would recommend using an IDE / Text Editor that gives hints or "intellisense" of "valid" html, css and javascript... This will save you alot of time and frustration.
Here is a solution...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[name=type_selector]").change(function () {
            var $category = $(this);
            $("div[class=widget_group_div]").each(function () {


                if ($category.parent().text() == $(this).children("p").html().trim()) {

                    if ($category.prop('checked')) {
                        $(this).children().show();
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).children().hide();
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul id="classification_selector">
            <li>widget_a<input type="checkbox" name="type_selector" value="widget_a" checked="" /></li>
            <li>widget_b<input type="checkbox" name="type_selector" value="widget_b" checked="" /></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="y_scroll_div">
            <div class="name_div"><h3>Item 1231</h3></div>
            <div class="widget_group_div">
                <p class="widget_group_name">
                widget_a
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="name_div"><h3>Item 23232</h3></div>
            <div class="widget_group_div">
                <p class="widget_group_name">
                widget_b
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, so you changed .text() to .html().trim() and removed the label class="widgets_name" element. I currently use aptana in pydev mode, and just basically write html in notepad++, can you recommend a free html javascript IDE or a know a plugin for aptana? Thanks again.

Comment: Yup that's it, you will hardly use the label tag, I also removed it from inside your H3 tags. I haven't used Aptana but apparently its really good, I'm fortunate enough to use Visual Studio with a few amazing Nuget packages. Just Google for "intellisense plugin for aptana". That should put you on the right track.

Comment: You can still use .text() instead of .html(), but you must use the trim (it trims off new line characters, spaces etc.)

Comment: Ok thank you again, I use the labels so that people don't have to click exclusively on the checkbox to get it to check, guess I got carried away with anything displaying text, and I will do the search, thanks.